# Unable to properly set up react-boilerplate: "npm ERR! ngrok - platform darwinarm64 is not supported."

Tags: apple-m1, ngrok, react-boilerplate

I am trying to set up react-boilerplate for the first time on a new M1 Max MacBook Pro and continue to get this error message after running `npm run setup`:

```
    npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path /Users/ssc/Documents/Development/website/node_modules/ngrok
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command sh -c node ./postinstall.js
    npm ERR! ngrok - platform darwinarm64 is not supported.
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/ssc/.npm/_logs/2021-10-31T06_18_18_426Z-debug.log
```

I have been unable to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This appears to be the same issue that I'm experiencing, but not sure I understand their solution: https://githubmemory.com/repo/bubenshchykov/ngrok/issues/201

Answer (score 8):

If you update ngrok to the latest version, which (at the moment) is `4.1.0` and  run again, it should work.

Comment: Also one more thing to note is to make sure package.json is updated with version 4.1.0 for ngrok. I missed to check that initially thinking it will be there but foundout the issue was at package.json where version was 3.1.1

Comment: It's still not working on macbook pro with m1 chip :(

Comment: Thanks, upgrading the ngork version to `4.1.0` worked for me in Macbook pro with M1 chip